# Laravel and oauth2: Issuing access token if the user has logged in using "remember me"

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, remember-me

I'm trying to implement **remember me** functionality to our app which uses Laravel 5.1 and [this oauth2 library](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel).

When a user logs in using **remember me** Laravel's session is correctly logging them in and calling `Auth::user()` returns their user object but I need the server to issue an access token. What I want is if the user lands on our page and was last logged in with **remember me** checked that they are issued an access token immediately without entering their credentials again.

Does this plan sound plausible or am I severely misunderstanding oauth2 authorization? I can't seem to find enough info on how to implement this flow or if it is even the recommended path.